# how to create a swipe effect like fruit ninja

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, graphics, swipe

I'd like to add a "wow effect" ;)... when the user swipe from left to right. I have zero expirence in graphics behind dotnet build in controls. 
I need links, book names, keywords and any tips that can show me how to achive swipe effect in winform or wpf or other presentation form that is on the dot net framework. 
thanks

[image: swipe finger in fruit ninja examples]

Comment: You probably want to start with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649090(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks this answer my next question how to make my animation work. Yet I'm after what it seems to me... a complicated animation... and i'd like to see if it is too complicated mathematics before I dive in.

Comment: Maybe [this fruit ninja clone porject](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-fruit-ninja-inspired-game-with-unity--cms-22145) will give you some inspirations. In Section 15 the swipe effect is explained. It uses Unity so you can't just use the code in Winforms or Wpf but use it for reference

Comment: How about trying to draw dots on the screen where you swipe first. Then progress to simple lines. Then to a spline shape with effects. Don't try to solve the whole problem at once.

Comment: My point is. First learn how to track mouse locations. Then learn how to draw shapes on the screen. Then learn how to make those shapes move. Then tie it all together. This is too big a question for a stack overflow question. Make some attempt then come back with specific problems about your code.

Comment: thank you all... for years i wanted to learn graphics but I thought it involves alot of matrix transaction and it was too complicated for me... I'll follow your guide and see if I can make through the challenge... thanks:)